# How to get artist name from music file by using php..?

Tags: php, audio, metadata, id3

I have a music file having artist name or author name.I want to fetch author details by using php.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state the format of the music file, but if it's nothing too exotic, the easiest way would probably be to use [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/).